# how to call a function (or directive) only when tab is selected in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm new in angularjs, I have page with 2 tabs.I create tabs using directives, I use $http to get json from my server.my problem is I don't want to request my server until user decide to see my other tab. how can I do this?
here is my directives :

```
var sdmtab = angular.module('sdmTab', []);

sdmtab.directive('tab', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div role="tabpanel" ng-show="active" ng-transclude></div>',
    require: '^tabset',
    scope: {
        heading: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, tabsetCtrl) {
        scope.active = false;
        tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope);
    }
};
});
sdmtab.directive('tabset', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'app/components/directiveTemps/tabset.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'tabset',
    controller: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.tabs = [];
        self.addTab = function addTab(tab) {
            self.tabs.push(tab);
            if (self.tabs.length === 1) {
                tab.active = true;
            }
            self.select = function(selectedTab) {
                angular.forEach(self.tabs, function(tab) {
                    if (tab.active && tab !== selectedTab) {
                        tab.active = false;
                     }
                 });

                 selectedTab.active = true;
             };
         };
     }
  };
 });

sdmtab.directive('teamsq', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'app/components/directiveTemps/teamSquad.html',
    bindToController: true,
    controllerAs: 'teamsq',
    controller: function($http, $log, userInfo) {
        var self = this;
        userInfo.then(function(answer) {
            var sid = answer.data.data.current_team.sid;
            var tid = answer.data.data.current_team.tid;
            self.team = [];
            self.bang = 'shirin';
            $http.get(webservice + "/team?token=" + token + "&team_id=" + tid + '&season_id=' + sid).success(function(response) {
                var players = response.data.players;
                angular.forEach(response.data.players, function(player) {
                    player['imageURL'] = "http://sdm.tarafdari.com/sites/default/files/players/150x150/" + player.pid + ".png";
                });
                self.team = response.data;
            });
        });

    }
};
});
```

here is my html :

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Details">
       ...
   </tab>
   <tab heading="Other infos">
       <teamsq></teamsq>
   </tab>
</tabset>
```

I want teamsq directive,only request when my 'other info' tab is selected.

Comment: you can try ng-if condition on 'other infos' tab. if tab is selected, only then it will call teamsq directive.

Comment: @MansiParekh I'm new in angular,can you be more specific plz??

Comment: how will you know that which tab is selected on page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little editing in my directive,I used action local sope in my tab directive to bind my directive to an external function,

```
sdmtap.directive('tab', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div role="tabpanel" ng-show="active" ng-transclude></div>',
    require: '^tabset',
    scope: {
        heading: '@',
        action: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, tabsetCtrl) {
        scope.active = false;
        tabsetCtrl.addTab(scope);
    }
  };
});
```

and simply in my tabset directive template I add action property to ng-click of my tab beside of select function :

```
<a href="" role="tab" ng-click="tabset.select(tab);tab.action()">{{tab.heading}}</a>
```

and in original template I add showSquads() function as action property to directive

```
<tab action="showSquads()" heading="{{'Team Squads'| translation}}">
```

and create showSquads() function in my controller, now when I click on my tabs, other than tab functionality, my custom function can be run for every tab

here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vfO7RKq4U4WcSxajHLpZ)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you only want to issue the request once (first time user clicks it).

You can bind an attribute to the directive `teamsq` scope, say `loadContent`:

```
scope: {
    loadContent: '='
},
```

For tab `other info`, pass in `<teamsq load-content="actions.loadOtherInfo"></teamsq>`. Here `actions.loadOtherInfo` is an attribute on outside controller. Add an `ng-click` to the tab `other info`, clicking it will set `actions.loadOtherInfo` to true. Inside the directive `teamsq`, simply use:

```
if (scope.loadContent && !scope.isLoaded) {
    scope.isLoaded = true;
    $http.get(webservice + "/team?token=" + token + "&team_id=" + tid + '&season_id=' + sid).success(function(response) {
        // ...
    });
}
```

`ng-if` will destroy and recreate the DOM structure every time (hence initiates the directive every time), I do not think it is a good solution for you.

Comment: I add loadContent to teamsq directive,and load-content="loadOtherInfo", but how can i set loadContent to true in my ng-click? see I set ng-click to tabs,function select on tabseet directive is invoke when tabs are click.how can i set loadContent  to ture in it?

Comment: Oh, the [directive two-way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) ensures that when you change `loadOtherInfo` outside the directive, the directive will receive an updated value of `loadContent` and update the view. (Of course, better to use some object to bind, say `actions.loadOtherInfo`).

Comment: my problem is I dont know how to change it :( in my directive controller loadContent='test2' dosent change anything in {{loadOtherInfo}} in my template, can you plz help me?

Comment: Oh, you change from inside directive? Then use object to bind: `actions.loadOtherInfo`. Reference: [Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: thanks @joy, you help me a lot in solving my problem,but I can't understand what u mean correctly and cannot solve my problem your way ,+1 for your help ;)

Comment: well, please put it to some JSFiddle/Plunker/Codepen demo. Code will tell the story.